# How can I create new applicationhost.config file in IIS Express Server?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I had to delete my applicationhost.config, because VS 1012 didn't deal with it.
How can I create it?
thank you.

Answer (score 38):

Just run IISExpress and it will recreate the file for you. The exe is located at: "c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not having luck doing this, it just throws this error when I run iisexpress.exe: 

An error occurred while reading configuration information. Make sure that the co
nfiguration file C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\IISExpress\config\applic
ationhost.config exists, it is accessible, and contains valid configuration info
rmation.

Answer (score 10):

After you deleted `applicationhost.config` you do not need to run `iisexpress.exe` manually, you can simply load your project in `Visual Studio` and run it. Visual Studio will take care of that plus it will change `applicationhost.config` with settings for that project specified in project Properties window (not mouse menu properties).

[image]

It will add corresponding override section at the bottom of `applicationhost.config`

```
<location path="...WebServices">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Website projects using Visual Studio 2019:**

When working with a website project on your workstation using IISExpress, Visual Studio creates and references the `applicationhost.config` file located in the following location:

`<your solution file folder>\.vs\<your solution name>\config\applicationhost.config`

*NOTE: the .vs folder is a hidden folder.*

It appears to me that Visual Studio is creating `applicationhost.config` by copying the contents of an `applicationhost.config` from this location:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationhost.config`

[Credit for the above location goes to Matthew MacFarland, in his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789448/32700]

You can copy the content from that location into your project's `applicationhost.config` and move forward.

Of course, you might need to repeat any steps in Visual Studio that would have modified the contents of `applicationhost.config` or repeat any changes you've made.

I have experienced a total loss of my project's `applicationhost.config` contents by editing the file while my project was open in Visual Studio 2019.

Thus, if you are going to manually change your `applicationhost.config` - I recommend that you make a backup copy prior to making changes, just in case the file is different that the template.

Further, an alternate way to recover a lost or corrupt `applicationhost.config` is to create a new Visual Studio Solution, copy the files from the old solution folder *except* the old solution file (of course) and the hidden `.vs` folder.  Then use "Add Existing Website" to add the project(s) to your new solution.  Visual Studio will setup all the necessary stuff under the `.vs` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Per my 2019 Visual Studio, deleting the file and starting the project automatically created a new one. I made a backup of the file first just in case.