# Where does Visual Studio copy the applicationhost.config file in the .vs folder from?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

Visual Studio creates a hidden folder in the solution root of web projects named .vs. Inside there is a config sub-folder with an **applicationhost.config** file. If the .vs folder is missing Visual Studio will create it again either when I open the solution or maybe when I start the debugger.

I assume that this **applicationhost.config** file is being copied from some default location. I wish to find the source file and make some changes so that my preferred settings will be in effect by default.

I am currently using **Visual Studio 2019 16.3.7**.

Where does Visual Studio copy this file from?

Answer (score 5):

I found **applicationhost.config** in these locations on my PC:

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer
2. C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer
3. C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\IISExpress\config

I altered each systematically and found that in my case Visual Studio 2019 is copying the file from path 1.

Comment: It would be an unreliable approach, as any future update of IIS Express will overwrite your changes. In short, don't have any "preferred setting" of your own.

Comment: @LexLi That is a very good point. The 2 settings I alter from default are changing anonymous and windows authentication from Deny to Allow since we prefer to set these in the Web.config of each project. I would like to hear of any alternative method you know of that might make this easier to manage.

Comment: @MatthewMacFarland 2 possible suggestions to resolve concerns from LexLi: 1. Keep a document on how to setup new projects that would include a step to modify the settings, or 2. Comment your web.config where you are modifying those settings to specify the changes required in applicationhost.config.

Answer (score 0):

The `applicationhost.config` is copied from

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config

You can get `%windir%` from the `set` command in a command window. (usually C:\windows)

From [Microsoft Forum](https://forums.iis.net/t/1186392.aspx?How%20to%20edit%20applicationHost%20config%20) User lextm...aka Lex Li

> You are encouraged to modify this file via appcmd.
>   http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/ Run
>   this command at an elevated command prompt is enough. To edit the file
>   directly, you need to elevate Notepad.exe and then open it. This is
>   not recommended unless you are quite familiar with the syntax. The
>   history folder contains the old copies of the config files, and
>   editing them does not make changes to current IIS settings.

Comment: On my PC the the inetsrv folder is present but empty. I am using IISExpress instead of the full IIS so that might explain it.

Comment: @Lex Li...Though it may not be a good idea...none the less it is where the original copy lies.

Comment: @Lex Li I'm not sure I understand. If the config file is not present on my system in this location then how can Visual Studio be using that copy. I've confirmed it does not use the copy in the IISExpress\config folder. The real location it is copying from is still unknown. I must edit the copy in .vs everytime. I'll find it eventually!

Answer (score -1):

The help documents `iisexpress /?` /config help states:

```
The full path to the applicationhost.config file. The default value is the IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config file that is located in the user's Documents folder.
```

Of course you can change the path to whatever using the argument as well.

Comment: This is not the location that Visual Studio is copying the config file from. I edited this file, deleted my .vs folder, and then started the debugger. Visual Studio created a new .vs folder and applicationHost.config file but the settings I added in the IISExpress were not present in new .vs folder. Visual Studio is clearly copying this file from some other location. Very mysterious.

Comment: When you say "...added in the IISExpress", are you referring to the IIS settings in the project properties window?

Comment: Hi Kevin, No, I mean the applicationhost.config file that is located in Documents\IISExpress\config. One of the answers said that this is where Visual Studio copies the file from when it creates the files in the .vs folders. It does not work that way for me.